# How to read, alter, and update back the item values inside <soapenv: Body> tag in AfterReceiveRequest() method

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, interceptor, idispatchmessageinspector

I am now implementing `AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)` method of  `IDispatchMessageInspector` interface to intercet the `WCF` `SOAP` message.

`System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request` as below

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <To soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://localhost:8993/TLS.svc/soap</To>
    <Action soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/TLS/GetMerchant</Action>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetMerchant>
         <tem:item1>value1</tem:item1>
         <tem:item2>value2</tem:item2>
      </tem:GetMerchant>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I would like to read and alter the value of `<tem:item1></tem:item1>` `<tem:item2></tem:item2>` and update back to    `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request` without damaging other message original properties

```
<soapenv:Envelope ... >
    <soapenv:Header>
        <To soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" ... </To>
        <Action soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" ... </Action>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <tem:GetMerchant>
            <tem:item1>Updatedvalue1</tem:item1>
            <tem:item2>Updatedvalue2</tem:item2>
        </tem:GetMerchant>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: You need to use MessageContract if you want to tweak the structure of the soap XML message.

Comment: What do you have problem with? The reading, or changing the message.

Comment: reading and updating

Comment: show the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

This post describes the way you can handle it at Dispatcher level, which will allow you to intercept all incoming messages. You just need to understand and read it carefully.
https://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector